# java how to import a class in a jar package

Tags: java

I want to introduce the servlet package, to use

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

Where should such commands be imported, and where should my jar package be placed?

But after unzipping, put the javax directory under the directory of my java file to succeed, but I always feel that this should not be the correct way
What I want is to put all the jar packages in the lib directory and then import them into the Java program. what should I do?

Comment: You should never unzip libraries. Jar files need to be added to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dependency management tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)
You just need to add your dependency to pom.xml and it will handle the rest.
After that you can import that dependency to your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the jars without unzip in the classpath.

If you use maven just add this dependency into pom.xml